# How to find child of a class in c#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, tree

I am here again to find some help.
I want to find a way to find child of come class for example if we double click on asRSap we have children of this class, in other way the inheritance
 [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdTvR.jpg)

I think I have to use treeview. I do not necessarily need the answer but a way to find because i am very lost
thank you

Comment: Show your code, not images ...

Comment: I don't even ahve a idea about how to do sorry.. I just want an idea not the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think reflection is the word you're looking for. There is a lot of documentation to be found on the web, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203474/register-all-declared-child-classes-of-a-class-in-c-sharp) SO article for instance. Using reflection, you can inspect your code in runtime. Perhaps with some [recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554103/recursively-get-properties-child-properties-of-a-class) functions you can navigate all the way through your class hierarchy and find what you're looking for.